# Redis multiple requests

Tags: ruby, redis

I am writing a very simple social networking app that uses Redis.

Each user has a sorted set that contains ids of items in their feed. If I want to display their feed, I do the following steps:

1. use `ZREVRANGE` to get ids of items in their feed
2. use `HMGET` to get the feed (each feed item is a string)

But now, I also want to know if the user has liked a feed item or not. So I have a set associated with each feed item that contains ids of user who have liked a feed item.

If I get 15 feed items, now I have to execute an additional 15 requests to Redis to find out, for each feed item if current user has commented on it or not (by checking if id exists in each set for each feed).

So that will take 15+1 requests.

Is this type of querying considered 'normal' when using Redis? Are there better ways I can structure the data to avoid this many requests?

I am using redis-rb gem.

Comment: pipelining maybe? or a Lua script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily refactor your code to collapse the 15 requests in one by using pipelines (which redis-rb supports).

You get the ids from the sorted sets with the first request and then you use them to get the many keys you need based on those results (using the pipeline)

With this approach you should have 2 requests in total instead of 16 and keep your code quite simple.

As an alternative you can use a lua script and fetch everything in one request.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of database (Non-relational database), you have to make a trade-off between multiple requests and include some data redundancy.

You should analyze each case separately and consider some aspects, like:

1. How frequently this data will be accessed?
2. How much space this redundancy will consume?
3. How many requests I will have to do, in order to have all data, without redundancy?
4. Performance is an issue?

In your case, I would suggest to keep a Set/Hash or just a JSON encoded data for each user with a historical of all recent user interaction, such as comments, likes, etc. Every time the user access the feeds you just have to read the feeds and the historical; only two requests.

One thing to keep in mind, every user interaction, you must update all redundant data as well.